# Filter Today's Date in MDX

Tags: date, filter, mdx

Hi I am trying to put a dynamic date filter (like today's date) in a MDX query, but I cannot get any result from the query, can some one help to check what is it wrong with my query?

I first tested the MDX query with a specified dated value, the query is

```
WITH MEMBER [Yesterday] AS VBAMDX.Format(VBAMDX.Now()-1,"MM/dd/yy")

select {[Measures].[Order Root Total], [Measures].[Yesterday]} on columns,
filter ([D Date].[DAY ID].&[09/19/13],
[Measures].[Order Root Total]>0) on rows
from [Root Product Profit and Sales]
```

It return the result

```
            Order Root Total    Yesterday
09/19/13    1481.2225483463         09/19/13
```

Then I tried:

```
WITH MEMBER [Yesterday] AS VBAMDX.Format(VBAMDX.Now()-1,"MM/dd/yy")

select {[Measures].[Order Root Total], [Measures].[Yesterday]} on columns,
filter ([D Date].[DAY ID].&[Yesterday],
[Measures].[Order Root Total]>0) on rows
from [Root Product Profit and Sales]
```

Then I return nothing..

Can Someone Please help me! Much Appreciate!!!

Answer (score 2):

You would have to use `StrToMember`, as `Yesterday` is a measure, and cannot directly be used in a member name. I would suggest defining Yesterday on the `[D Date].[DAY ID]` hierarchy instead of the `Measures` one:

```
WITH MEMBER [D Date].[DAY ID].[Yesterday] AS 
     StrToMember('[D Date].[DAY ID].&' + VBAMDX.Format(VBAMDX.Now()-1,"MM/dd/yy") + ']')

select {[Measures].[Order Root Total], [Measures].[Yesterday]} on columns,
filter ([D Date].[DAY ID].[Yesterday],
[Measures].[Order Root Total]>0) on rows
from [Root Product Profit and Sales]
```