# Get current month in where statement MDX

Tags: sql-server, mdx

Lets say I want the current months sales from each store. I would do it with first make a calculated member:

```
SELECT
{[Measures].[Total sales]}
ON 0,
{[Organization].[Storename]} ON 1
FROM SALES
WHERE
[Period].[Period].[Month].&[2015]&[11]
```

To automate this to always be the last month, I would do something like this:

```
WITH  MEMBER [Measures].[Full Date] as 'NOW()'
MEMBER [Measures].[What Month] as 'MONTH([Full Date])'
Member [Measures].[What Year] as 'YEAR([Full Date])'

SELECT
{[Measures].[Total sales]}
ON 0,
{[Organization].[Storename]} ON 1
FROM SALES
WHERE
[Period].[Period].[Month].&[What Year]&[What month]
```

However, I get no data doing this. What do I do wrong? How should I do this?

Comment: Look into using `STRTOMEMBER()`

Comment: does your cube contain future dates or is the last member in the date dimension today's date?

Comment: The cube contain dates a couple of years ahead sadly, so the currentmember/lastmember doesn't work.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Filter Today's Date in MDX](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18911036/filter-todays-date-in-mdx)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's looking for a member by the name`&[What Year]&[What month]` as if there is a literal member by this name in the "month" level.

Instead use `StrToMember` function inside your `WHERE` clause.

```
StrToMember("[Period].[Period].[Month].&[" + FORMAT([Measures].[What Year], "") + "]&["+ FORMAT([Measures].[What Month], "") + "]")
```